# Why is RandomizedSearchCV() returning a worse score than the default classifier setting here?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification

I am using the following code to try and tune the parameters of the MLPClassifier:

```
hidden_layer_sizes = ([x for x in itertools.product((10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 53, 73, 100), repeat=1)] + \
                       [x for x in itertools.product((10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100), repeat=2)] )
                       #[((len(clean_df.columns))+1,)] )]
#print(hidden_layer_sizes)
alpha = [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100]
activation = ['identity', 'logistic', 'tanh', 'relu']
solver = ['lbfgs', 'sgd', 'adam']
learning_rate = ['constant', 'invscaling', 'adaptive']

random_grid = {'hidden_layer_sizes': hidden_layer_sizes,
               'alpha': alpha,
              'activation' : activation,
              'solver': solver,
              'learning_rate': learning_rate}

prec_metric = make_scorer(precision_score)
k = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False)

mlp = MLPClassifier()

mlp_random = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = mlp, param_distributions=random_grid, scoring=prec_metric,
                               n_iter=100, cv=k, n_jobs=-1, verbose=3)

mlp_random.fit(clean_df, target)
print("Best parameters found: " + str(mlp_random.best_params_))
print("Mean test score from Randomized Search CV: " + str(mlp_random.cv_results_['mean_test_score'].mean()))
```

Surprisingly to me (after a couple of hours waiting) this Randomized Search actually returned a worse mean test score of 60% than when the MLPClassifier is trained with the default settings here which gave me 76% accuracy:

```
mlp = MLPClassifier()

scores = cross_val_score(mlp, clean_df, target, cv=10)
print("Full features: mean of the scores: {:.2f}".format(scores.mean()))
```

Any idea what's going?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comparing your parameter grid and the defaults, I would guess that the problem is in either `hidden_layer_sizes` or `alpha`.

- The default value of `alpha` is `1e-4` whereas your grid's lowest value is `1e-2`. Possibly, you are regularizing too much and this results in underfitting. Check in your `cv_results_` how did the models with lower `alpha` perform with respect to others and potentially adjust the grid.
- Looking at the `hidden_layer_sizes` grid, all of them have the size
  of the first layer <= 100 which is the default.

Note that a model using default hyperparameters is often a very good benchmark and when you give the RandomizedSearchCV so many degrees of freedom (uniform sampling), you cannot guarantee that all of the sampled hyperparameters will make sense. In fact, I would guess that in your case a lot of them don't.

UPDATE:
To export the cross validation results to csv do:

```
pd.DataFrame(mlp_random.cv_results_).to_csv('export.csv')
```

Comment: Good spot. How exactly do I pull up a readable copy of cv_results_?

Comment: See the updated answer. Just inspect the results and try to determine which parameters lead to better scores.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The lower values of C did seem to perform better indeed. I guess I'll rerun the test with lower levels of alpha.

Comment: Yeh, focus on the alpha and hidden_layer_sizes, I would keep things like solver and activation equal to the defaults.

Comment: Do you suggest I ignore learning_rate also? The documentation suggests it's only used when the solver is equal to sgd? I'm only going to use 'adam' as my solver so I assume I should ignore it?